# Xamarin.iOS how to: include multiple fat frameworks with same entry point funcs?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios, dynamic-library

I have two fat frameworks with two slices each (arm64 and x86_64): MyDbEngine.framework and MyDbClient.framework.  Each framework contains the same entry point funcs: MyDbConfigure(), MyDbInit(), and MyDbDeInit().  I'm trying to figure out how to add BOTH of these frameworks to an Xamarin.iOS iOS app project such that the app installs both frameworks but when I call the entry point it needs to be done in a specific framework (MyDbClient.framework in this case).  I can't seem to figure out how to do this due to how DllImport on iOS forces the use of `__Internal` rather than specifying a specific framework to load.

For example, in my Xamarin.Android app project I can add the individual dynamically linked shared object (.so) file equivalents for my frameworks (MyDbEngine.so and MyDbClient.so) under the appropriate \lib\arm64-v8a\ or \lib\x86_64\ folders and then specify the `[DllImport(libZenDb, EntryPoint = "ZenDbConfigure")]` to explicitly load the entry point from MyDbClient.so.

Is there a way to do this in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was mashing up the documentation for "[Use C/C++ libraries with Xamarin - Wrapping the Native Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/#wrapping-the-native-library-stage-2)" with the documentation on including frameworks and assuming the DllImport call had to reference "__Internal" to load the frameworks.

As it turns out, this can be accomplished by specifying the exact framework to load. So continuing my previous example, the correct call for what I'm trying to do would be:

`[DllImport("MyDbClient.framework/MyDbClient, EntryPoint = "MyDbConfigure"]`

Comment: Hi , if problem has been solved , remember to mark answer when have time .